# Azure Database Federation Error

Tags: azure-sql-database

tried creating a federation from using sql server management studio but got this weird error after executing the CREATE FEDERATION command.

here is the query and the error result after executing it.

[image]

I just hope someone has ran into this before.

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Federations are no longer supported in Azure SQL Database. Depending on your application, consider putting each Federation member into its own dedicated database in an Elastic Pool, or sharding your data across a few databases. The different alternative application patterns with links to the feature documentation are discussed in more detail here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-design-patterns-multi-tenancy-saas-applications/.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Torsten